# AD queries using AD not chasing referrals

Tags: vba, powershell, active-directory, ldap, referrals

I am logged into `DC=domain,dc=company1,dc=com` I am using VBA to query AD. I can query `GC://dc=company1,dc=com` with no issues. But when I try to query `GC://dc=company2,dc=com` I get no results. It appears that my code will not chase referrals.

I am able to run the queries using PowerShell so I know it should work. I just can't figure out how to get the VBA code to work so it chases referrals.

Here is the VBA code I am using that **does not** work. It just prints "not found" even though the same code does find something when using PowerShell.

```vb
Dim adConnection As ADODB.Connection
Dim adCommand As ADODB.Command
Dim adResults As ADODB.Recordset

Set adConnection = New ADODB.Connection
Set adCommand = New ADODB.Command

adConnection.ConnectionTimeout = 600
adConnection.Provider = "ADSDSOObject"
adConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"

Set adCommand.ActiveConnection = adConnection
adCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
adCommand.Properties("Size Limit") = 0
adCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE
adCommand.Properties("Timeout") = 600
adCommand.Properties("Cache Results") = False
adCommand.Properties("Chase referrals") = ADS_CHASE_REFERRALS_ALWAYS
adCommand.CommandTimeout = 600

adCommand.CommandText = "<GC://dc=company2,dc=com>;(&(objectClass=user)(samAccountName=user1));samAccountName;Subtree"

Set adResults = adCommand.Execute

If Not adResults Is Nothing Then
    If Not adResults.EOF Then
        Debug.Print adResults.RecordCount
    Else
        Debug.Print "not found"
    End If

    adResults.Close
End If
```

Here is the PowerShell code that **does** work:

```
[System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry] $objDERoot = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("GC://dc=company2,dc=com")
[System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher] $objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($objDERoot)
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"
$objSearcher.ReferralChasing = "All"
$objSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(samAccountName=user1))"
$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samAccountName")
[System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection] $colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()
Foreach ($objResult in $colResults)
{
    $objResult.Properties.Item("canonicalName")
}
```

Comment: Exactly what does "does not work" mean? Do you get an error? If so, what is it? Any message? Which line of code is throwing it? Or your code just prints "not found"? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: What is the value of `ADS_CHASE_REFERRALS_ALWAYS`? Is it defined anywhere? Should be `96`, or `&H20 Or &H40`.

Comment: If you change the target to a GC in the company1 domain, you get the same number of results with both methods?

Comment: @mats-mug: I edited to explain that it prints "not found" even though it shouldn't. And yes, that variable equals 96.

Comment: @mathias-r-jensen: yes.